# How to merge alternate lines to each following column?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, merge, newline

I'm trying to merge alternate lines regarding each column

input:

```
ind1 T G T
     T T T 
ind2 G G T 
     G T T
```

desired Output:

```
ind1 TT GT TT
ind2 GG GT TT
```

I tried these commands:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' <input> output
```

and

```
paste - - <input> output
```

but it only merge alternate lines but adding the whole line, not considering columns; e.g:

```
ind1 T G T T T T

ind2 G G T G T T
```

Any idea using bash or python?

Comment: Is this a representative example, or merely an illustration? Particularly, in your actual input, is the number of columns fixed? Is the data always the single letter `T` or `G`? Is the leader always `ind` followed by a number? Are those tabs or spaces?

Comment: is a representative example. The numbers in the columns are fixed; data always in single letters (but not only T or G). the leader can be any string not necessarily followed by number of letters. The delimitador are tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR%2 {n=split($0,a); next} 
            {for(i=1;i<n;i++) $i=a[i+1] $i; 
             print a[1],$0}' file

ind1 TT GT TT
ind2 GG GT TT
```

**Explanation** split the odd numbered rows into columns.  Merge with the next row and print. The even numbered rows have one field less, shift and print accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for, 
It is incredible how awk is versatile for any situation hahahahaha

Answer (score 2):

A non-awk solution, since you asked for answers in bash or python:

```
cut -f 1-4 -d ' ' in   | # the delimiter is a tab here
  sed 's/^/>/'         | # replace the start of the line with a >
    while read a b c d   # read the fields
    do if [[ "$a" = '>' ]]                     # if > then a second line
       then printf "$A\t$B$b\t$C$c\t$D$d\t\n"  # so stack them
       else A=${a#'>'}; B=$b; C=$c; D=$d;      # else set for stack later
       fi
    done
```

If you want it fast for large amounts of data, I'd use perl.
Or python.

Or C. I hate awk. Not knocking it's ability - I just don't like it.

Comment: Thanks Paul Hodges, but the problem is that it has more than 150000 fields, so it is easier without having to set the fields a-d to be read. 
Thanks a lot for the explanation, I will probably use it for smaller files.

Comment: Then I'd *definitely* use Perl and make it code in a repo with warnings and strict and lots of comments. Perl has quite a bit of history in bioinformatics.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **awk** solution (for your current input):

```
awk -F'\t' -v FPAT='[^[:space:]]+' 'NF>3{ h=$1; for(i=1;i<=3;i++) a[i]=$(i+1) }
              NF==3{ print h,a[1]$1,a[2]$2,a[3]$3 }' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
ind1    TT  GT  TT
ind2    GG  GT  TT
```